# How to return value 0 if div is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, is-empty

I have a div which has a dynamic value. When `#div1` is empty, I would like to show a simple value `"0"`.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
if ($('#div1').is(':empty')){
   //and here I don't know to return value 0 as text
}
</script>
```

Comment: You want a string "0"? How is this 0 going to  be used?

Comment: Returning it is easy: `return '0'`. The hard part is figuring out what exactly you're trying to do with that returned text. Unfortunately your current code won't do anything with it.

Comment: I assume that by "return 0" you mean "show 0"? If so, where do you want to show it?

Comment: Yes show 0, for example if div is empty  show "some text", in my case 0.

Comment: Where do you want to show it?

Comment: in the same div (I got it with some research and solve it)

Comment: You seem to be using jQuery, so I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial first. It should cover everything you need to know for this: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/ .

Comment: My answer for me was found here and now it works nice and smooth..https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/. Thanks all for answers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
if ($('#div1').is(':empty')) {
 $('#div1').text("0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to contain the text "0", just do `$('#div1').html("0");`

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe like this:

```
if ($('#div1').is(':empty')) {
 $('#div1')[0].innerHTML = '0'; // u can add more DOM elements in this way
}
```

For example:

```
    var moreDom = '<div id="someDiv"><p>some text in div<p></div>' + 
                    '<div id="someDiv2"><p>some text in div2<p></div>';
    $('#div1')[0].innerHTML = moreDom;
```

Comment: This won't work. jQuery objects don't have an `innerHTML` property (granted, this might not be jQuery, but it very much looks like it).

Comment: U have right. It should be $('#div1')[0].innerHTML = moreDom. But then it will not look to great.

Comment: How it looks doesn't matter if it doesn't work :P Of course you could simply use the jQuery API: `$('#div1').html('0')` which works *and* looks better.

Comment: And how about that? https://jsfiddle.net/2dqaqyjo/ :) But with API you mentioned, it will look better :D

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. You seem to have implied that the current solution doesn't look as "nice" as the previous one. All I was saying is that it doesn't matter how "nice" it looks if it doesn't work. Meaning while the previous version may have looked "nicer", it didn't work.